# Do you need to add permissions for plugins to the app's AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: flutter

Android plugins in Flutter define permissions inside the **plugin** AndroidManifest.xml such as this one:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="io.flutter.plugins.connectivity">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Should I also define these permissions inside my app's AndroidManifest.xml inside `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`for the permission to be granted?

Comment: this might help you, http://cogitas.net/android-runtime-permission-flow-flutter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they should get merged automatically. Open your project in Android Studio, change the left tree pane to 'Android', expand the app/manifests branch and open `AndroidManifest.xml`. At the bottom of the editing pane, change from `Text` to `Merged Manifest`. In this view you see a color-coded merged manifest, showing the permissions merged in from your plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you have to add them to the Android Manifest inside your app. The permissions for your app are set in this file.